# Java - Can't break out of this recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, return

I am trying to implement a depht first search alogrithm (my code is probably horrible, I'm sorry). Now I wanted to make this a recursive method but I just can't seem to be able to break out of it once the end condition is met. The first if-conditional you see in the method should break out of the method. When I was debugging the project it reached the return statement and then immediately jumped to the end of the method. But instead of stopping the whole thing it went back to the `while(!allNeighboursVisited)` loop and went on in an infinite loop.

I was trying to solve this by myself which did not work and started searching in the web, but I just could not find any solution to my problem.

EDIT: Decided to share the link to the project on my github for you guys to try it out: https://github.com/Equiphract/Maze

EDIT 2: Updated the code; I hacked it together so please don't expect anything that is pleasant to look at :)

Here is the recursive method:

```
public void depthFirstSearch(int x, int y, Tile[][] maze) {
    // Return method after every Tile is visited.
    if (this.visitedCounter == maze.length * maze[0].length) {
        this.stack.clear();
        return;
    }

    Tile currentTile = maze[x][y];
    Random r = new Random();
    int neighbourAmount = currentTile.getNeighbourAmount();
    boolean allNeighboursVisited = false;
    int stopCounter = 0;

    // If it is a new Tile, mark it as visited
    if (!currentTile.isVisited()) {
        currentTile.setVisited(true);
        this.visitedCounter++;
        stack.add(currentTile);
    }

    // Check if neighbours are not yet visited and "visit" one of them.
    while (!allNeighboursVisited) {
        int random;
        do {
            random = r.nextInt(neighbourAmount);
        } while (this.excludeList.contains(random));

        Tile neighbour = currentTile.getNeighbours().get(random);
        if (!neighbour.isVisited()) {
            if (neighbour.getX() == currentTile.getX() - 1) {
                currentTile.getWall(4).setOpen(true);
                neighbour.getWall(2).setOpen(true);
            } else if (neighbour.getX() == currentTile.getX() + 1) {
                currentTile.getWall(2).setOpen(true);
                neighbour.getWall(4).setOpen(true);
            } else if (neighbour.getY() == currentTile.getY() - 1) {
                currentTile.getWall(1).setOpen(true);
                neighbour.getWall(3).setOpen(true);
            } else if (neighbour.getY() == currentTile.getY() + 1) {
                currentTile.getWall(3).setOpen(true);
                neighbour.getWall(1).setOpen(true);
            }
            this.excludeList.clear();
            depthFirstSearch(neighbour.getX(), neighbour.getY(), maze);
            if (this.visitedCounter == maze.length * maze[0].length) {
                this.stack.clear();
                return;
            }
        } else {
            this.excludeList.add(random);
            stopCounter++;
        }

        if (stopCounter == neighbourAmount) {
            allNeighboursVisited = true;
        }
    }

    // If every neighbour has already been visited, go back one Tile.
    if (!this.stack.isEmpty()) {
        this.stack.remove(this.stack.size() - 1);
        if (!this.stack.isEmpty()) {
            Tile backtrackTile = this.stack.get(this.stack.size() - 1);
            this.excludeList.clear();
            depthFirstSearch(backtrackTile.getX(), backtrackTile.getY(), maze);
            if (this.visitedCounter == maze.length * 3) {
                this.stack.clear();
                return;
            }
        }
        this.excludeList.clear();
    }
}
```

You know what, here is the Tile-Object (sorry for the high amount of edits in this short period):

```
public class Tile {
    private ArrayList<Wall> walls;
    private ArrayList<Tile> neighbours;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private boolean visited;

    /*
     * Constructor of the Tile class.
     */
    public Tile(int x, int y) {
        this.walls = new ArrayList<Wall>();
        this.neighbours = new ArrayList<Tile>();

        this.walls.add(new Wall(1));
        this.walls.add(new Wall(2));
        this.walls.add(new Wall(3));
        this.walls.add(new Wall(4));

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.visited = false;
    }

    /*
     * Returns the ArrayList walls.
     */
    public ArrayList<Wall> getWalls() {
        return walls;
    }

    /*
     * Returns the value of visited.
     */
    public boolean isVisited() {
        return visited;
    }

    /*
     * Sets the value of visited to a specified value.
     * 
     * @param visited a boolean value
     */
    public void setVisited(boolean visited) {
        this.visited = visited;
    }

    /*
     * Returns a wall with the specified position.
     * 
     * @param position the position of the wall
     */
    public Wall getWall(int position) {
        for(Wall w : this.walls) {
            if(w.getPosition() == position) {
                return w;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int getNeighbourAmount() {
        return this.neighbours.size();
    }

    public ArrayList<Tile> getNeighbours(){
        return this.neighbours;
    }


    /*
     * Adds a Tile to the ArrayList neighbours-
     * 
     * @param t a Tile
     */
    public void addNeighbour(Tile t) {
        this.neighbours.add(t);
    }

    /**
     * @return the x
     */
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    /**
     * @return the y
     */
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting! Please give me the Tile object, then I'll take a look.

Comment: I provided a github link where you can view the whole program. The java files are in /src/maze. Edit: wait before reviewing the code, I made some changes to it throughout the day, I will edit the post soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I found a solution to my question. It is far from perfect and needs a lot of optimisation, maybe one of you guys want to do that and post it here^^.

My main mistake was not adding returns after each time I invoked the method recursively, which resulted in an endless-loop.

Here is my solution:

```
public void depthFirstSearch(int x, int y, Tile[][] maze) {
    // Return method after every Tile is visited.
    if (this.visitedCounter == maze.length * maze[0].length) {
        this.stack.clear();
        return;
    }

    Tile currentTile = maze[x][y];
    Random r = new Random();
    int neighbourAmount = currentTile.getNeighbourAmount();
    boolean allNeighboursVisited = false;
    int stopCounter = 0;

    // If it is a new Tile, mark it as visited
    if (!currentTile.isVisited()) {
        currentTile.setVisited(true);
        this.visitedCounter++;
        stack.add(currentTile);
    }

    // Check if neighbours are not yet visited and "visit" one of them.
    while (!allNeighboursVisited) {
        int random;
        do {
            random = r.nextInt(neighbourAmount);
        } while (this.excludeList.contains(random));

        Tile neighbour = currentTile.getNeighbours().get(random);
        if (!neighbour.isVisited()) {
            if (neighbour.getX() == currentTile.getX() - 1) {
                currentTile.getWall(4).setOpen(true);
                neighbour.getWall(2).setOpen(true);
            } else if (neighbour.getX() == currentTile.getX() + 1) {
                currentTile.getWall(2).setOpen(true);
                neighbour.getWall(4).setOpen(true);
            } else if (neighbour.getY() == currentTile.getY() - 1) {
                currentTile.getWall(1).setOpen(true);
                neighbour.getWall(3).setOpen(true);
            } else if (neighbour.getY() == currentTile.getY() + 1) {
                currentTile.getWall(3).setOpen(true);
                neighbour.getWall(1).setOpen(true);
            }
            this.excludeList.clear();
            depthFirstSearch(neighbour.getX(), neighbour.getY(), maze);
            return;
        } else {
            this.excludeList.add(random);
            stopCounter++;
        }

        if (stopCounter == neighbourAmount) {
            allNeighboursVisited = true;
        }
    }

    // If every neighbour has already been visited, go back one Tile.
    if (!this.stack.isEmpty()) {
        this.stack.remove(this.stack.size() - 1);
        if (!this.stack.isEmpty()) {
            Tile backtrackTile = this.stack.get(this.stack.size() - 1);
            this.excludeList.clear();
            depthFirstSearch(backtrackTile.getX(), backtrackTile.getY(), maze);
            return;
        }
        this.excludeList.clear();
    }
}
```